# Identifying variables that make up Comp1, 2, 3 & 4 Eigenvalues in R

Tags: r, eigenvalue

I have this eigenvalue output. How do I identify the variables that are embedded in Comp 1, 2, 3 & 4?

```
eigenvalue percentage of variance cumulative percentage of variance
comp 1  2.9839729             74.5993220                          74.59932
comp 2  0.7106996             17.7674897                          92.36681
comp 3  0.2858553              7.1463834                          99.51320
comp 4  0.0194722              0.4868049                         100.00000
```

Comment: You should write repeatable code which produce your output

Comment: Pls I'm quite new to statistics and R...What repeatable code are you talking about please?

Comment: I don't  know which package You used and how. Give me a code which was used to produce the resault you attached

Comment: I used the factoextra and FactoMineR packages. Then i derived the PCA scores and the Eigen values as shown below:  test_mac<- PCA(hist_mac_pca_1, graph = T), 

test_mac$eig